LWC datatable cell focus
I created a lwc component, however when i click on the cell it focuses and shows this outline color blue, is there a way to remvoe this? i tried checking the documentation from slds and implemented the css tags both on datatable class and cellattributes, none of them worked and i couldn't figure out what needs to be added


put below thing is css of your LWC,
watch magic happen
:host{
    --slds-g-shadow-inset-inverse-focus-1: null;
}


Thank you. It worked, by any chance where do you learn this things or is there any documentation aside from slds page or cheatsheet. I'm kinda new to overriding slds css components.

I jumped into devtools and kept digging till I found the slds hook for particular style
